# Disconnected set with its connected complements

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$X=\mathbb C - (A\cup B)$ where $A=[0,\infty)$ and $B=\{rcis\theta :r=\theta, 0\leq \theta\leq \infty\}$ 
Honestly, I do not know how to find its connected complements. Can I interpret X as (C - A) U (C - B)
Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\mathbb{C}-(A \cup B) = (\mathbb{C}-A) \cap (\mathbb{C} - B)$

Using that you can calculate each complement individually and then intersect them.

Comment: $C-A=\{z \in \mathbb C : z = x +iy, y <0\}$ and $C - B = \{z \in \mathbb C : z \neq rcis \theta\}$ . Intersection of them is a combination between the two. right? It becomes the union of open sets, hence it is not connected, right? How to express the sets?